# Riemann-integration problem

Tags: proof-writing, riemann-integration

### Here is the exercise

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann-integrable. Prove that $f^+$, $f^-$ and $|f|$ are also Riemann-integrable, when
>
> $$f^+=\begin{cases} 
>       f(x) & f(x)\geq 0 \\
>       0 & otherwise 
>    \end{cases}$$
>
> $$f^-=\begin{cases} 
>       -f(x) & f(x)\leq 0 \\
>       0 & otherwise 
>    \end{cases}$$

This problem seems so obvious. Why wouldn't $f^+$ be integrable? Anyway, I need to prove this using this hint:

"$f$ is Riemann-integrable if with every $\epsilon>0$ there exists [step functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) $h\leq f\leq g $ such that $\int h -\int g <\epsilon$."

I have no idea where to start...

Comment: I like a lot your comment *This problem seems so obvious. Why wouldn't $f^+$ be integrable?* Asking yourself why it should be will be better to bring you to the road of a proof! **Hint** build step functions $g^+, h^+$ from $h$ and $g$ such that $h^+\leq f^+ \leq g^+ $ and $\int h^+ -\int g^+ <\epsilon$.

Comment: Haha glad you liked my comment. Anyway, this doesn't seem to proof anything to me: Let $h$ and $g$ be step functions such that $h\leq f\leq g$. Now it's obvious that $h^+\leq f^+\leq g^+$ and as $f$ is Riemann-integrable, then $\int h^+ -\int g^+<\epsilon$ thus making $f^+$ also Riemann-integrable.

Comment: @Matematleta Thanks I'll try to understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove the Riemann integrability of $f^+$. A similar proof can be done for $f^-$.

As $f$ is Riemann-integrable, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists step functions $h \leq f\leq g $ such that $\int h -\int g <\epsilon$.

Now define $h^+ = \max(h,0)$ and $g^+ = \max(g,0)$. You can verify that:

1. $h^+, g^+$ are step functions.
2. You have $h^+ \le f^+ \le g^+$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.
3. **And also $g^+ - h^+ \le g-h$ for all $x \in [a,b]$**. This implies $0 \le \int (g^+-h^+) \le \int (g-h) \le \epsilon$

And concludes the proof.

Comment: I guess this is as simple as it gets as I immediately understood it. Thanks.